# The term for putting wallpapers on the walls

Tags: word-request

Do you call it "to glue the wallpapers" as we do in Russian or do you use some different verb?

Comment: You put/paste/stick wallpaper onto walls. You can use wallpaper as a verb such we have wallpapered the walls of a room.

Comment: @Khan this should better go as an answer! :)

Comment: A lot of building/decorating terms seem to be capable of this noun to verb usage… painting, wallpapering, plumbing, wiring - only joinery seems to have escaped… wooding doesn't really work ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as everything already mentioned, you can also hang wallpaper.

> Brian couldn't answer the phone because he was busy hanging wallpaper.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Khan's answer, you can also use **wallpaper** as a verb in its own right:

> We decided **to wallpaper** Annie's bedroom. ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://books.google.ru/books?id=pqlRO2jdI2gC&lpg=PA1072&dq=%22decided%20to%20wallpaper%22&hl=ru&pg=PA1072#v=onepage&q=%22decided%20to%20wallpaper%22&f=false))
>
> Mama and Bernice decided **[to wallpaper](https://books.google.ru/books?id=yJNk2L9Vj44C&lpg=PA30&dq=%22decided%20to%20wallpaper%22&hl=ru&pg=PA30#v=onepage&q=%22decided%20to%20wallpaper%22&f=false)** the living room and had a great time doing it, which was unusual, because they snarled at each other most of the time.
>
> We want **[to wallpaper](https://books.google.ru/books?id=QDgBHp9XaSUC&q=%22want%20to%20wallpaper%22&dq=%22want%20to%20wallpaper%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=CXK_VNLnHOr9ywOz5IHYCw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw)** new plaster walls. What preparation is necessary?

Comment: @Khan actually did say this; he just used the verb 'to wallpaper' in the present perfect, which would be the norm for BrE in his sentence.

Comment: @δοῦλος - thanks for the comment! I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

"We wallpapered the room."

"We put up wallpaper."

"We hung wallpaper."